# C# Cefsharp Get RAW Data Before Implemented/Display into table

Tags: c#, cefsharp

First, I'm sorry for the bad language.

I am building a Cefsharp WinForms application (beginner), the purpose are getting the raw data.

I can get the response data using resource handler, but the response data are being encrypted and the encrypted data are being decrypted in the browser and then displayed as table.

1. Can I get the value of the data before or after it's displaying in the table, or can I get the function inside the browser so I can call it later using the javascriptasync or are there any other options?
2. Is it possible to get the datasource of the table because the displayed table are using mat-table cdk-table

Thanks